# Pause a subroutine until button pressed?? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The code im working on is a bit of a mess, but heres a dumbed down version of what im trying to do:

Lets say there is a program that generates a random number, and displays it to a texbox.
The user must then press either of two buttons, to determine whether the number is odd or even. if they answer correctly, the score is incremented, and the amount of questions they have answered is incremented also. if it is wrong, then only the amount of questions answered is incremented. A new number is generated and displayed each time the user answers. The whole thing lasts for two minutes. Heres an example of what it could look like:

```
    Public RandomNumber as integer = 0

Sub Main()
    Dim QuestionsAnswered as integer = 0
    Dim CorrectlyAnswered as integer = 0
    Dim timer as new stopwatch
    timer.start()
    While timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < 120000
        RandomNumber = Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 1000)
        MyTextBox.Text = RandomNumber
        'WAIT UNTIL EITHER BUTTON IS PRESSED HERE
    End While
    MsgBox("Well Done you scored: " & CorrectlyAnswered & "/" & QuestionsAnswered)
End Sub

Private Sub EVEN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnA3.Click
        If RandomNumber Mod 2 = 0 then
            CorrectlyAnswered += 1
            QuestionsAnswered += 1
            Main()
        Else
            QuestionsAnswered += 1
            Main()
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub ODD_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnA3.Click
        If RandomNumber Mod 2 = 1 then
            CorrectlyAnswered += 1
            QuestionsAnswered += 1
            Main()
        Else
            QuestionsAnswered += 1
            Main()
        End If
    End Sub
```

I'll mention again, it is not the above code I have a problem with, its just the idea. I'm new to programming in forms and this whole getting an input from a button seems to be a nightmare. I'm guessing there are many solutions to keeping the program idle for a while but I'm sure someone her knows a better solution. Using a function, rearranging the code, pausing it, whatever as long as it works!

I'd be very thankful for some help.

Comment: Are you saying that the user has a limited amount of time to answer the question?

Comment: The loop will execute until the timer hits 2 mins, generating a new number on each pass. i need it to pause and allow for an input

Comment: What you are trying to do is wrong. DO NOT use a loop. Just display the first number and be done. When the user clicks a `Button`, then display the next number. If you want to limit the amount of time the use a `Timer`. It will raise an event when its `Interval` expires to tell you that time is up. Basically, there is no answer to your question because you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Structure your code properly and there is no need to pause because WinForms apps are effectively paused all the time that you're not executing code.

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate the comment by @jmcilhinney.

Your Form needs 2 buttons and a label set up in the designer. You also need to drag a timer from the Tool Box to the form and it will appear in the component tray. You can select the Timer an set properties just like a control. Set the interval property to 120000. You probably should set the names of your controls to more meaningful names. If you do, be sure to change the names in the code everywhere the control name appears. I just use the default names available in my test program.

WinForms applications are event driven. Controls have events. When the user or the system causes an event your code runs. Otherwise the program just sits there. You need to switch you mind around from Console applications which need loops to keep going.

Please check the comments in the code.

```
Private r As New Random 'An instance of the .net Random class
Private CorrectAnswer As Integer
Private QuestionCount As Integer
Private IsEven As Boolean

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'This is where the program begins
    DisplayNumber()
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

'This event handles the click of both buttons. Note the Handles clause 
Private Sub ButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click 'Text would be Even, Odd respectively
    'The sender tells us which button was clicked.
    'This will increment the Form level variables
    If sender Is Button1 AndAlso IsEven Then
        CorrectAnswer += 1
    ElseIf sender Is Button2 AndAlso Not IsEven Then
        CorrectAnswer += 1
    End If
    QuestionCount += 1
    DisplayNumber()
End Sub

'This method is called from both the Form.Load and ButtonClick. To avoid duplicating code
'we write a separate method.
Private Sub DisplayNumber()
    'Using the random class declared at Form level will return a random number up to 1000
    Dim num = r.Next(1000)
    'Mod divides two numbers and returns only the remainder.
    'Even numbers will always return 0 as remainder
    IsEven = (num Mod 2 = 0) 'The parenthesis are not necessary but I don't like 2 equals in a line of code.
    Label1.Text = num.ToString
End Sub

'Set Timer1.Interval which is in milliseconds to 120000 in the Form Desiner
'The Tick event will occur afer 2 minutes
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Button2.Enabled = False
    Timer1.Stop()
    Label1.Text = ""
    'The message box is using an Interpolated String designated by the $ preceding the quote sign.
    'This type of string can use variables surround by braces embedded exactly where you want them to appear.
    'It is an easier method than String.Format
    MessageBox.Show($"Time is up. You had {CorrectAnswer} correct response out of {QuestionCount} questions.")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a timer component from the ToolBox with interval of 1000 ms (from properties). Fundamentally two buttons namely Odd & Even, Start button should be added. And for some decoration, add Labels to show time counting.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private seconds As Byte ' Since we don't need larger numbers for 2 min counting
    Private correct As Byte
    Private answers As Byte
    Private random As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Start()
        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button2.Enabled = True
        Button3.Enabled = True

        Shuffle()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        seconds += 1

        Label1.Text = seconds.ToString + " seconds / 120 seconds"

        If seconds = 120 Then ' To count till 120000 ms (120s)
            Label1.Text = "Press ""Start"" to get started"
            Timer1.Stop()
            seconds = 0

            Button2.Enabled = False
            Button3.Enabled = False

            Label2.Text = correct.ToString + " correct / " + answers.ToString + " answers"

            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click, Button2.Click
        Shuffle()

        If random Mod 2 Then
            correct += 1
            answers += 1
        Else
            answers += 1
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Shuffle()
        random = Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 1000)
        Label2.Text = random.ToString
    End Sub
End Class
```

Hope it helps you.

[image: Project OddEven]